# Making Dirt Ground out of an Sphere?

Tags: mesh, materials

I recently got this Procedural Dirt Shader and want to use it as a Ground ( Plane?) but i cant find out how!
I started working with Blender a few Weeks ago so im not used to the Controlls.

Maybe you could help me make a Dirt Ground out of the Dirt Ball!
Thx in advance!

[image]

Comment: you say "I recently got this Procedural Dirt Shader", but could you please tell a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a plane (Add > Mesh > Plane), unwrap it (u > unwrap) and apply the material to it in the material tab of the properties window.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Unwrapping may not be required depending on the material setup, but can't hurt either.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! Thats what i did but when doing that the Plane is just Flat and the Bumbs and Stuff from the Ball Shader dont show up there... Maybe you could help me <3